# Connect local Jupyter Hub to Azure Databricks Spark Cluster

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I have one Azure Databricks cluster. Although it provides notebook, my team is more familiar with using Jupyter Lab which they can upload offline-csv, install python packages.
I want to setup a Jupyter lab which can connect to the Spark Cluster.

Although databricks allow using remote kernel to access it - https://databricks.com/blog/2019/12/03/jupyterlab-databricks-integration-bridge-local-and-remote-workflows.html, it can't read local files on Jupyter lab.

Is there any way to use spark cluster with a local jupyter lab like https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/connect-to-remote-kerberized-hive-from-a-local-jupyter-notebook-to-run-sql-queries-83d5e548d82c?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you prefix a magic command with a `%%`, it will take the rest of the cell as its argument, which means `%%local` is used to send data to Spark cluster from Local instance.

**Install databrickslabs_jupyterlab locally**:

```
(base)$ conda create -n dj python=3.8  # you might need to add "pywin32" if you are on Windows
(base)$ conda activate dj
(dj)$   pip install --upgrade databrickslabs-jupyterlab[cli]==2.2.1
(db-jlab)$ dj $PROFILE -k
```

**Start JupyterLab:**

```
(db-jlab)$ dj $PROFILE -l
```

**Test the Spark access:**

```
import socket

from databrickslabs_jupyterlab import is_remote

result = sc.range(10000).repartition(100).map(lambda x: x).sum()
print(socket.gethostname(), is_remote())
print(result)
```

For more details, you can refer to [Install Jupyter Notebook on your computer and connect to Apache Spark on HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-install-locally), [Kernels for Jupyter Notebook on Apache Spark clusters in Azure HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-jupyter-notebook-kernels) and [Sending data to Spark cluster from Local instance](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic/blob/master/examples/Send%20local%20data%20to%20Spark.ipynb)